# iPhone mail fecthing time < 15 minutes

Tags: ios, mail.app, iphone

Is it possible to set iPhone mail fecthing time < 15 minutes under iOS 5?

The current configuration only allows 15 minutes data pushing, but I need to react to my mail fast. Is there a way to get around this or an application that could help this?

Comment: Yeah. Push it. [/nerd]

Comment: What kind of address is it? Gmail, Yahoo Mail, something else?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is <15 mins data pushing, question edited :)

Comment: Who is your email provider?

Comment: Hi, it's gmail.

Answer (score 3):

Set Push to ON (under settings->Mail, Contacts, Calendar->Fetch New Data). You can even select push or pull for each single mail account under Advanced.

[image]

Comment: Who is your cell carrier and do they get that cool icon from Apple or do you need to modify the system to show the red colors there?

Comment: That's Vodafone's logo, though I don't know about the rest of your question. :)

Comment: This is a good tip, but it's dependent on your mail provider supporting push. Great if you use Exchange or Yahoo, but it's not supported for IMAP accounts (like Gmail).

Comment: Yes I knew this setting, as you can see the minimum is Every 15 minutes, I would like to set it smaller than that..if not possible, I would wish to have an apps if there is available..I am using gmail. (Sorry for the typo "pull" in the question, I have edited it..what I mean is "push")

Comment: If you set us Gmail as an exchange account, it can do push.

Comment: What do you mean exchange account? And can it push say every 2 minutes?

Comment: No longer possible with gmail exchange accounts https://www.engadget.com/2013/03/26/gmail-push-notification-no-longer-works-with-mail-on-new-ios-dev/